# Functions - Is this a trick?

Tags: functions

The function $f(x)=\frac{x-1}x$ is defined on the domain $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$.

Is $f(x)$ invertible? If an inverse function exists, find a formula for the inverse and state its domain and range. If an inverse does not exist, explain why not.

I can easily find the inverse, which is $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$, and the domain and range, but this seems to easy and most likely be a trick. Is this too easy to be true, or is this actually ***easy***?

EDIT: I am fairly certain that this function is injective...

Comment: In **some cases**, it really is that easy: by showing a function that fulfills what it must, you show $\;f\;$ is invertible. Advice: show directly $\;f\;$ is injective and obviously onto is image.

Comment: If you want something interesting, try finding $f(f(x))$ and $f(f(f(x)))$

Comment: I've never seen a trick math question that didn't have a warning. Nobody's trying to fool you.

Comment: I mean in a math course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that this function is injective, suppose $f(a) = f(b)$ for some $a,b$ in the domain of $f$. Then we have that

$$\frac{a-1}{a} = \frac{b-1}{b}$$

It follows that

$$b(a-1) = a(b-1)$$
$$ba-b=ab-a$$
$$-b=-a$$
$$a=b$$
It is thus injective.

Now, let's look at the image of this $f$. A number $c \in \Bbb R$ lies in the range of $f$ if there exists some $a$ in the domain such that

$$c = \frac{a-1}{a}$$
$$ca = a-1$$
$$a(c-1) = -1$$
$$a = -\frac{1}{c-1}$$

Thus, $a$ will exist if and only if $c \neq 1$ (which checks out since the numerator of the function is never equal to the denominator). Thus, the range of $f$ is $(-\infty,1) \cup (1,\infty)$.

Your inverse is correct, and since $f$ is bijective (when mapped to its range) it has domain and range flipped. Thus, the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $(-\infty,1) \cup (1,\infty)$, and the range is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$

Comment: Just passing by, the whole analysis gets much simpler by remarking that $f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x} =  1- \frac{1}{x}$.